# eclipse - how to enable "mark occurrences" for any text and in all files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

If I have a C-file opened and I highlight `var1`, the editor will automatically highlight all occurrences of `var1`.

```c
int main()
{
  int var1=0;
  int var2 = var1 + 55;

  return 0;
}
```

However, it will not highlight all instances of `int` in the same manner.

Furthermore, if I open a `.s` file - which is set as type **Assembly Source File** automatically by CDT - no occurrences will be marked.

In the following assembly file, I'd like occurrences of `L97` to be marked when I highlight one occurrence for easy navigation.

```
    ...
    b   .L97
.L98:
    ldr r0, .L99
    mov r1, r4
    bl  printf
    movs    r0, #0
.L97:
    pop {r2, r3, r4, pc}
.L100:
    ...
```

How do I enable **mark occurrences** for all text ***and*** in all file types?

In Notepad++, I opened a window, typed two lines of some random text `abcd`, double-clicked one of them and it automatically highlighted the other without me even setting a file-type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Notepad++** marks the occurrences of **strings**, whereas **Eclipse** marks occurrences of **variables**.

In the following example, if the first `var1` is selected, Eclipse marks only the occurrences of this variable, but neither identically named variables in a different scope nor the string `var1` in a comment:

```c
int main()
{
    int var1=0;
    int var2 = var1 + 55;
    {
        int var1 = 42; // var1
        int var11 = 43;
    }
    return 0;
}
int foo()
{
    int var1 = 44;
    return var1;
}
```

To search and mark a string in one or more files, you can use file search: *Search > File...*.

To jump to the next occurrences of a selected string press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this for any file type. Occurrence highlighting requires an editor which understands the syntax of the programming language you are editing (Java, C, C++, ....). You would need to find an Eclipse editor for the particular assembly code to get occurrence highlighting.

Comment: But in notepad++, I opened a window, typed two lines of `abcd`, double-clicked one of them and it automatically highlighted the other without me even setting a file-type.

Comment: A simple version could be done in the plain text editor, but that editor currently doesn't support that feature.